# php write to file - the file become to large (optimize file size or other approach)

Tags: php

I want to create a feed (.txt file) with my products from DB (mysql)

Each line from the feed file should like this:
Product Code | Category | Brand | Price | ... and other 8 columns.

The code that i use:

```
$feedFile = fopen(APP_PATH."external_feed.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$feedRow = ''; 
$s = '|';
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
while ($row = $mp->getRows()) {
    $feedRow = $feedRow .$row['ClientCode'].
        $s.$row['CategoryName'].
        $s.$row['Brand'].
        $s.$row['Name'].
        $s.$row['Price'].
        $s."in stock".
        $s."free shipping".
        $s."no warranty".
        $s.$url_to_product.
        $s.$url_to_image.
        $s.$row['Description']."\n";
    fwrite($feedFile, $feedRow);
}
fclose($feedFile);
```

After finishing writing the file with 2275 products the file is to large 12GB.

Is there a better aproach to write large data to file? Or how can i optimize writing to file to become smaller?

Comment: 12GB seems like it's too large for only 2275 products. My assumption is that you're writing more than you think. I created an export feature years ago that exported hundreds of thousands of lines of code in a similar way  (for products). It had 72 columns. Those files were in the 150MB range. Check your output.

Comment: If there's 12GB of data, then there's 12GB of data. You can then apply the regular compression algorithms (gzip, zip, bzip2, etc.) to make the physical file size smaller. Are you sure that the data actually _is_ 12GB? That sounds like _a lot_ for just 2275 products. Also - `fputcsv` is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are concatenating `$feedRow` in while loop. This will keep appending previous row again and again.

Initialize `$feedRow` to blank in while loop

```
while ($row = $mp->getRows()) {
    $feedRow = '';
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or use `fgetcsv` which is made for writing separated values to a file.

Comment: @MatsLindh I thought its `fputcsv`?

Comment: Yes, can be done with `fputcsv`. Tried to answer in simplest form without the need to change much in existing code :).

Comment: You are right @Samir ... i see it. I have $feedRow = '';  ousite the while :)

Comment: Now the file have 10 MB....but i think there is a bug somewhere ... i should get in the file 2275 rows and i get 5490 of rows...

Comment: is there `\n` in values for any of the columns? If yes that will break the csv and split the row into 2. If that's the case, you will have to replace it before writing to the file.

Comment: Yup. that was it. Thx a lot @Samir